# squid reverse proxy - forward https traffic

Tags: squid, accelerator

I have squid functioning as a reverse proxy with 2 apache and 1 iis server as backends. A page Login.aspx on the iis server redirects to a https:// page on the same server. I have used urlpath_regex to direct all incoming requests for aspx/asp pages on squid to the iis server.

When I type **https://www.example.com/Login.aspx** I would like squid to simply forward all https requests to the iis server without bothering to decrypt the ssl (I would like this decryption to be done on the iis server only). How can I do this?

I have tried to add https_port 192.168.124.41:443 but this asks me for an ssl certificate which I do not have (it's on the iis server). I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 0):

With Squid in reverse mode, you can't. There are two ways:

1. Use NAT.
2. Allow Squid to decrypt the traffic. Then Squid with communicate with the server with SSL too.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder why Squid insists on decrypting the traffic in reverse mode?

Comment: It doesn't decrypt anything, it's the SSL endpoint. If you don't want that, don't use Squid, use NAT. A proxy in that case, doesn't make any sense.